# Swift calling delegate from didSet

Tags: ios, swift, properties

I have a delegate for my `GameState` class. I am trying to call the `gameStateUpdated` method every time `playing:Bool` is changed using `didSet`. I keep getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on my delegate. Even checking it for nil. 
When `playing` gets set I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and I am positive that my `delegate` is not nil.

```
var stateDelegate:GameStateDelegate?
var playing = false {
    didSet {
        stateDelegate?.gameStateUpdated(self.playing)
    }
}
```

I know I don't want to reference `self.playing` from the setter of a computed property. But this shouldn't be a computed property.

**EDIT**

The same thing happens if I use `stateDelegate?` or `stateDelegate!`. I had the optional chaining before but it wasn't working so I figured I'd try forcing it.

Comment: I'd recommend to write always `stateDelegate?.gameStateUpdated(self.playing)` for optional delegate types. If the delegate is nil, nothing happens, if not the method will be called. It's the same behavior as sending a message to nil in Objective-C

Comment: @vadian I had it as an optional chaining before and it doesn't work. I changed it to `!` to try something new.

Comment: if `stateDelegate` is not `nil`, and you are still getting the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error, then it is likely that the problem isn't in the `didSet` code, but somewhere in the `gameStateUpdated` method that you are calling. Or perhaps elsewhere in your code. Why do you believe the error is coming specifically from `didSet`?

Comment: can you isolate the code which causes problems and upload it on github?

Comment: @RomanSausarnes You are right. I just tried `if stateDelegate != nil{}` with a blank content of the if and it did not `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. It must be the method it is calling.

Comment: As @appzYourLIfe suggested, the next place to look is inside `gameStateUpdated`. What happens there?

Comment: @RomanSausarnes It called a method called `togglePlay()` which was setting `playing = !playing` and setting the button states. It was infinite recursion as you and @appzYourLife stated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the problem is not related to the use of `!` then lets look for the issue somewhere else.

Maybe **infinite recursion**?

More specifically what happens inside `gameStateUpdated`? Infact if this method is changing the `playing` property then the `didSet` is triggered again and again...

You can check this easily, just add a `breakpoint` to `didSet` or the following line of code.

```
print("didSet called")
```

If `didSet` gets called multiple times then this is the problem.

Comment: You are right. It was infinite recursion. I was calling that delegate method which was calling a method I wrote called `toggleButton` which was originally changing the state of playing from true to false. Thanks a lot.